# Formatting Point Count Data into simple Wide or Long format for Rarefaction

Tags: r, dataformat

I want to create species accumulation curves using rarefaction for my point count data at different survey points. I have point count data where every row is an individual observed, and the columns are all of the information associated with that individual. I want to format it into simple Long and Wide data formats. For example, a column for Point_Name, a column for Species, and a column for the number of individuals of each species seen at each point. I visit each point multiple times, so I think I also need the different trips reflected? [A screenshot of my raw original data. I don't know what the proper term for this type of format is, so if anyone knows that would be appreciated too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plwCR.jpg)
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! 1. Can you give us an example chunk of data to work with that maintains features like >1 visit and point-per-visit? You can use `dput()`. 2. Is each visit uniquely identified by Date? Combination of Date+Time? 3. Your data are already in long format. 4. You don't seem to actually want to reshape your data to wide/long. What you seem to want is to summarize it so you have 1 row per visit-species-point and a column with the # of rows corresponding to that. Is that correct? Example drawing/object of what you want would be helpful. If so, can help edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is summarize/aggregate your data into fewer rows. Since we don't have any data to work with, I'll provide some example data that are similar to your own and walk you through it.

#### Example data somewhat similar to your own

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Date = rep(c("2021-10-10", "2021-11-11"), each = 12),
  Time = rep("07:10:00", 24),
  Species = c(
    rep("CAKI", 2),
    rep("LEGO", 6),
    rep("CAKI", 3),
    rep("ANHU", 1),
    rep("CAKI", 5),
    rep("LEGO", 3),
    rep("CAKI", 1),
    rep("ANHU", 3)
  ),
  Point_Name = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 2), rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 2))
)
```

#### Summarize into long structure

```r
# Required packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Create a visit_id to identify each row's visit mapping then summarise 
# We'll assume that each visit is uniquely identified by a combination of date
# and time, but you can change the variables used in making the id as needed
aggregated <- df %>%
  mutate(visit_id = paste0(Date, Time)) %>%
  count(visit_id, Point_Name, Species, name = "n_obs")

aggregated
#>             visit_id Point_Name Species n_obs
#> 1 2021-10-1007:10:00          A    CAKI     4
#> 2 2021-10-1007:10:00          A    LEGO     6
#> 3 2021-10-1007:10:00          B    ANHU     1
#> 4 2021-10-1007:10:00          B    CAKI     1
#> 5 2021-11-1107:10:00          A    CAKI     5
#> 6 2021-11-1107:10:00          B    ANHU     1
#> 7 2021-11-1107:10:00          B    CAKI     1
#> 8 2021-11-1107:10:00          B    LEGO     3
#> 9 2021-11-1107:10:00          C    ANHU     2

# We can also add rows so that each combination of visit, point, and species
# appears in our data, with zeros assigned to those combos with 0 observations
# I'll break this down into individual steps

# Expand to get the desired object but without the number of observations
all <- aggregated %>% expand(visit_id, Point_Name, Species)

# Add the number of observations
all_with_obs <- aggregated %>% right_join(all)
#> Joining, by = c("visit_id", "Point_Name", "Species")

all_with_obs
#>              visit_id Point_Name Species n_obs
#> 1  2021-10-1007:10:00          A    CAKI     4
#> 2  2021-10-1007:10:00          A    LEGO     6
#> 3  2021-10-1007:10:00          B    ANHU     1
#> 4  2021-10-1007:10:00          B    CAKI     1
#> 5  2021-11-1107:10:00          A    CAKI     5
#> 6  2021-11-1107:10:00          B    ANHU     1
#> 7  2021-11-1107:10:00          B    CAKI     1
#> 8  2021-11-1107:10:00          B    LEGO     3
#> 9  2021-11-1107:10:00          C    ANHU     2
#> 10 2021-10-1007:10:00          A    ANHU    NA
#> 11 2021-10-1007:10:00          B    LEGO    NA
#> 12 2021-10-1007:10:00          C    ANHU    NA
#> 13 2021-10-1007:10:00          C    CAKI    NA
#> 14 2021-10-1007:10:00          C    LEGO    NA
#> 15 2021-11-1107:10:00          A    ANHU    NA
#> 16 2021-11-1107:10:00          A    LEGO    NA
#> 17 2021-11-1107:10:00          C    CAKI    NA
#> 18 2021-11-1107:10:00          C    LEGO    NA

# Replace the NA values in the number of obs column with 0s instead
no_na <- all_with_obs %>%
  mutate(n_obs = if_else(is.na(n_obs),
                         as.integer(0), n_obs))

no_na
#>              visit_id Point_Name Species n_obs
#> 1  2021-10-1007:10:00          A    CAKI     4
#> 2  2021-10-1007:10:00          A    LEGO     6
#> 3  2021-10-1007:10:00          B    ANHU     1
#> 4  2021-10-1007:10:00          B    CAKI     1
#> 5  2021-11-1107:10:00          A    CAKI     5
#> 6  2021-11-1107:10:00          B    ANHU     1
#> 7  2021-11-1107:10:00          B    CAKI     1
#> 8  2021-11-1107:10:00          B    LEGO     3
#> 9  2021-11-1107:10:00          C    ANHU     2
#> 10 2021-10-1007:10:00          A    ANHU     0
#> 11 2021-10-1007:10:00          B    LEGO     0
#> 12 2021-10-1007:10:00          C    ANHU     0
#> 13 2021-10-1007:10:00          C    CAKI     0
#> 14 2021-10-1007:10:00          C    LEGO     0
#> 15 2021-11-1107:10:00          A    ANHU     0
#> 16 2021-11-1107:10:00          A    LEGO     0
#> 17 2021-11-1107:10:00          C    CAKI     0
#> 18 2021-11-1107:10:00          C    LEGO     0
```

#### Convert long summary into wide

We can also convert this into a wider structure.

```r
# Finally we could make this wide format instead of long by, say, having only
# one row per visit/point with columns for species counts
no_na %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("visit_id","Point_Name"),
              values_from = "n_obs", 
              names_from = "Species")
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   visit_id           Point_Name  CAKI  LEGO  ANHU
#>   <chr>              <chr>      <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 2021-10-1007:10:00 A              4     6     0
#> 2 2021-10-1007:10:00 B              1     0     1
#> 3 2021-11-1107:10:00 A              5     0     0
#> 4 2021-11-1107:10:00 B              1     3     1
#> 5 2021-11-1107:10:00 C              0     0     2
#> 6 2021-10-1007:10:00 C              0     0     0
```